# Check read only status of CRichEditCtrl

Tags: winapi, mfc

I learnt today that the Clear() method of CRichEditCtrl only works when the control is not read only. I want to be able to restore the existing read only status once I've cleared the contents, but I don't see a way of checking the status in the first place. I could of course keep track of when it's being set to read only, but it'd be nice to be able to query it directly. Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what the `Clear` method does but you can probably clear it while its read-only simply by using `SetWindowText` with an empty string.

Comment: Yes, I'll just ditch clear and use that instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GetStye:

```
bool bReadOnly =  (m_wndRTFEdit.GetStyle() & ES_READONLY)!=0;
```